# JavaFX Rolling cylinder on meshview with

Tags: javafx, physics, kinematics, javafx-3d

What approach should I take to animate rolling of cylinder on custom meshview in JavaFx? Is there any sample (opensource) already available for this purpose?
Some kinematics or physics package to support javafx ?

Comment: Well Colliders and such aside, you could try to adapt jBullet: http://jbullet.advel.cz/
Although a good amount of effort is needed to get it going in JavaFX.
I "have" been working on a JavaFX port, but no where near ready for use (other projects jumped in)  .. 
For simply rolling the Cylinder a RotateTransition or Timeline could be used, for a "game loop" AnimationTimer is best.. 

I do have some "BASICS" setup in our project, Though the Cloth has been a pain to port to our Sampler.. Newer repo: https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz
repo with runnable Cloth sample: https://github.com/Birdasaur/FXyz